# Remove space to last text

Tags: spacing

Do you know a way to remove the space to the last text (or figure or anything that is visible on the pdf) ?

I want to write an environment, which has a fixed space to the last "thing", that will be visible on the pdf. So in short

```
text \\[5\baselineskip]
\begin{myenvironment}
```

and

```
test
\begin{myenvironment}
```

should give the same output.
I don't really have an idea how to do this.

I want a - for me - nice looking spacing between the "thing" and my environment, but I can't get all cases together. The explanation is that at the end of the environment, I have a space as well. This looks good when it is followed by normal text, but when another enmironmant comes after, the spacing gets a little to big. Also it looks really creepy when there already is a space like in the first code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Start the definition of `myenvironment` with `\par\addvspace{5\baselineskip}`. Maybe it's better if you're a bit more specific on what's the environment used for.

Comment: It's used to write mathematical essays. There I wanted to define my own structeres because I really hate the standard types. If this isn't possible, I thought I could define the end of the last myenvironment and just check whether it is text \begin{myenvironment} or two environments after each other. I just hoped the bigger case would be possible as well :)

Comment: That's where `\addvspace` enters the scene and why I asked you to show what your aim is.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to help. If I have text, then 5cm vspace and then start with myenvironment, I want to have the 5cm removed and then start with the environment. If there is no space, all is good and if I'm still in the middle of a line, a simple linebreak will be fine.